# How to change taskbar image through java?

Tags: java, windows, javafx-2, taskbar

When we are running any java application that time one java icon display on the taskbar like [image]

Now I want to change the java icon to another icon 
then how can I change that icon?
Currently I am using JavaFX.

Comment: See also [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18224184/418556).

Comment: *"I am using JavaFX"*  It would pay in future to mention that in tags as well as words in the question.  Don't expect us to go 'reading' your screen grabs for information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I followed what you want, but to me it looks like you want the icon of the stage to be changed. Try the code below:

```
yourStage.getIcons().add(new Image("my_icon.png"));
```

Comment: where i want to put the image file ?