# How to change the position of Jframe default icon?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, icons

Is there any way to change the position of the default java icon in the jframe so that it will appear right next to the title of the Jframe window?

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't. Unless you're willing to create a look and feel delegate which achieves the job you're looking for, which isn't nearly as easy as it sounds

Comment: Is it possible to edit current look and feel class to position the icon?

Comment: The "system" look and feel delegates the frame decorations to the OS directly, so you have no say in its creation

Comment: *"Is there any way to change the position of the default java icon in the jframe.."* There is no need to worry about such futzing when [running under OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21945380/418556) - no icon appears at all! On Windows it is down to user preference. E.G. on [my machine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18224185/418556) the window titles are configured to show on the left (right next to the icon), but on the [machine of mKorbel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21945380/418556) the titles are centered in the title bar and therefore not immediately beside the icon. It is user choice ..

Comment: .. and the programmer should not try and mess with the user's choice, or to be inconsistent with other apps. that are used on that machine.

Comment: I think this question should be closed since it is not possible to do it for a beginner like me