# Increase size of title bar in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying my hand in swing applications and would like to know if there is a way to increase the height of the title bar of a JFrame/JDialog?

[image]

And also Can I get rid of the Swing icon and replace it with an icon of my own choice?

Sorry if this is a repeated question/too silly , I just haven't found a suitable answer anywhere yet :( Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

> ..  if there is a way to increase the height of the title bar of a JFrame/JDialog?

Given that wold make that one app. inconsistent with all the other apps. that open on this machine, I'd sure hope not. (And as far as I know, 'no it is not possible'.)

> Can I get rid of the Swing icon and replace it with an icon of my own choice?

See [`JFrame.setIconImage(Image)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage-java.awt.Image-).

Comment: I added an icon of my choice in the title bar and it is very small and unclear now. Hence I was hoping to increase the size of the bar but I guess I will find a work around with changing the icons dimensions. Thank you :)

Comment: *"..I guess I will find a work around with changing the icons dimensions."* The OS will use whatever size of icon it prefers, and will scale the icon to suit (on Windows at least). See [Sizes of frame icons used in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224184/sizes-of-frame-icons-used-in-swing) for more details.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot :) that helped .