# Multiple JFrame icons on desktop for Java application

Tags: java, swing, jframe, icons, desktop

I want to create multiple icons on the desktop in my Java applications, calling another `JFrame` from my mainframe but only one icon is showing me on the desktop. Is there a possible method to do that? For example, if I have this ->

[image]

Can I have this? ->

[image]

Comment: Use `JFrame` for the one you want to show, and [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) for all others. `JDialog` does not show on the task bar.

Comment: *"Can I have this?"* It's certainly possible, by launching a second process (another JVM). Having said that, this app. should probably have **only** one frame, ***&*** have only a **single icon** in the task bar. What is it about your app. that makes you feel either makes sense? BTW: further to what @c0der was mentioning, see: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Oh, and nice to see some [familiar screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18224185/418556) as well. :)