# Is there a way to generate an icon from Graphics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, icons

Working in Java Swing I would like to be able to dynamically change the icon
of the `JFrame` as events happen in the code without having any .pngs. Is there any way to draw the image internally and have it then used as the icon,  so that I can do something like the below?

```
public void Icon(Graphics g){
    ImageIcon img = g.getImageIcon();
    myFrame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
}
```

Comment: You would generate all the `BufferedImage` icons before you create the GUI.  Then, during the events, you can change the `JFrame` icon.

Comment: Further to what @GilbertLeBlanc suggests, the icons used in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18224184/418556) are all generated at run-time.

Comment: You can implement the `Icon` interface, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: *"I was able to find a way to code this"* Actually if you took the guru hint from the thread I linked to (many different icon sizes might be used) along with the tip from @trashgod re implementing your own `Icon`, this would result in the most optimal solution. Many icons can be created (all different sizes) and set to the frame as a list. Only the used ones will be rendered, and won't suffer the vagaries of which resizing algorithm the JRE uses.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to input from Gilbert Le Blanc, Andrew Thompson I was able to find a way to code this by using buffed image and Graphics2D

```
public void Icon(){
   BufferedImage icon = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   Graphics2D g = icon.createGraphics();
   generateImage(g);
   myFrame.setIconImage(icon);
}
```

Where generateImage is some function or another to paint the graphics onto g.

Comment: You should also call dispose on the Graphics object after painting to it